# Embedding Excel within a WinForm application

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, webserver

I am doing a WinForm Application with framework 4.5.2 and Visual Studio 2017.

I create an xlsx file with `ClosedXML` and then I need to show it embedded in a form.

I have read a lot how to host Excel within a WinForm application, most to links points to WebServer.

I have tried to simplified [this example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15760/How-to-Integrate-Excel-in-a-Windows-Form-Applicati). Most of links points this, but it does not work to me.

To simplified I add a `webBrowser` to my form and a `buttom`

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      this.webBrowser1.Navigate(@"C:\adrress\Test.xlsx",false);
 }
```

Excel opens with the file, and the form shows a message saying "the navigation is canceled"

I need just to open the file inside the form.

How is the best way to do it?

Comment: Is your [OS 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438518/how-to-open-the-excel-xlsx-file-embeded-in-windowforms-control-in-64-bit-os)

Comment: it is 64 bit. But the program will run on differents Windows. 7-8 and IIS 11 or Chrome, from webBrowser... Thanks

Comment: .. did you read that linked question and the answer?

Comment: Thanks...I just read it. I had read it before but i did not know what it was talking about... So I need to use WebBrowser to 64 bit and detects the CPU bitness. How can i use webBrowser to 64 bits? Another question... VSTO can be used to open an Excel file in WinForm? Thanks!!